# Installed KB2729094 for x64/Windows 7, but still does not fix glyphs in IE10

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-10

I have installed Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 x64. First couple of days it ran fine, and they all of the glyphs for scrollbars, dropdown boxes, checkboxes, radio buttons etc disappeared and left behind a horrible looking square...

This is how it should look...

[image: How it should look...]

This is how it looks on my machine...

[image: How it really looks...]

So with that in mind, I have of course looked for the update/patch for this, which is [KB2729094](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2729094), which I have installed, and yet, the glyphs are still ruined/missing.

Here's the proof...

[image: Update for Windows (KB2729094) is already installed on this computer.]

Comment: Have you tried `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: @kinokijuf: I had exactly the same issue, the update said it was already installed and `sfc` didn't fix it either. I had to replace the font with a copy from another system.